bypass microsoft sing up captcha "funcaptcha" using 2captcha
so i go a result when i send the request and then i tried to inject it and post and some other metohds but no one worked right
is there any spisefic method or something i miss maybe ?
i was try to bypass the captcha i got the result but i didnt know how to inject it or post it to the frame of the captcha it's just not response anything...
async function solveFuncaptcha(driver) {
  try {
    console.log("Waiting for first CAPTCHA frame to load...");
    const firstFrame = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(By.css('iframe[id="enforcementFrame"]')),
      30000
    );
    console.log(
      "First CAPTCHA frame detected. Switching to enforcement frame..."
    );
    await driver.switchTo().frame(firstFrame);

    console.log("Waiting for second CAPTCHA frame to load...");
    const secondFrame = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(By.css('iframe[data-e2e="enforcement-frame"]')),
      30000
    );
    console.log("Second CAPTCHA frame detected. Switching to it...");
    await driver.switchTo().frame(secondFrame);

    console.log("Waiting for game core frame to load...");
    const gameCoreFrame = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(By.css('iframe[id="game-core-frame"]')),
      30000
    );
    console.log("Game core frame detected. Extracting public key...");

    const gameCoreFrameSrc = await gameCoreFrame.getAttribute("src");
    const publicKeyMatch = gameCoreFrameSrc.match(/pk=([^&]+)/);

    if (!publicKeyMatch) {
      throw new Error("Unable to find public key in game-core-frame src");
    }

    const publicKey = publicKeyMatch[1];
    console.log("Extracted public key:", publicKey);

    console.log("Switching back to default content...");
    await driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

    console.log("Attempting to solve CAPTCHA with 2captcha...");
    const result = await solver.funCaptcha({
      publickey: publicKey,
      pageurl: await driver.getCurrentUrl(),
      surl: "https://client-api.arkoselabs.com",
    });

    if (!result || !result.data) {
      throw new Error("CAPTCHA solving failed: No result from 2captcha");
    }

    console.log("CAPTCHA solved. Result:", result);

    console.log("Navigating back through the frames to submit the solution...");
    await driver.switchTo().frame(firstFrame);
    await driver.switchTo().frame(secondFrame);

    console.log("Submitting CAPTCHA solution...");
    await driver.executeScript(`
      parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
        eventId: "challenge-complete",
        payload: {
          sessionToken: "${result.data}"
        }
      }), "*");
    `);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error solving CAPTCHA:", error.message);
    return false;
  }
}

